# Need to enable a few days from already disabled weekends in datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have have disabled all the weekends in the jQuery datepicker. Now there is a requirement that I have to enable a few weekend dates.

I have tried adding in those dates to an array and then enabling them but it's not working. Current code is below which works fine for disabling weekends but I can't enable the specific dates I need. Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
  var availableDates = ["2018/12/22", "2018/12/23"]; // yyyy/MM/dd
  var unavailableDates = ["2018/12/25", "2018/12/26", "2018/12/27"]; // yyyy/MM/dd
  var unavailableDays = ["Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday"];

  function unavailable(date) {
    ymd = date.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    day = new Date(ymd).getDay();
    if ($.inArray(ymd, unavailableDates) < 0 && $.inArray(days[day], unavailableDays) < 0 && $.inArray(ymd, availableDates) < 1) {
      return [true, "enabled", "Order now"];
    } else {
      return [false, "disabled", "Delivery not available on this date"];
    }
  }

  $('#date').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the `availableDates` must override the other condition about weekends and `unavailableDates`...

So make if a separate condition. If it evaluates to true, just `return` (so the second condition won't be evaluated).

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
  var availableDates = ["2018/12/22", "2018/12/23"]; // yyyy/MM/dd
  var unavailableDates = ["2018/12/25", "2018/12/26", "2018/12/27"]; // yyyy/MM/dd
  var unavailableDays = ["Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday"];

  function unavailable(date) {
    ymd = date.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    day = new Date(ymd).getDay();

    if($.inArray(ymd, availableDates) >= 0){   // Evaluate availableDates first
      return [true, "enabled", "Order now"];
    }

    if ($.inArray(ymd, unavailableDates) < 0 && $.inArray(days[day], unavailableDays) < 0) {
      return [true, "enabled", "Order now"];
    } else {
      return [false, "disabled", "Delivery not available on this date"];
    }
  }

  $('#date').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak your condition a bit to work for available and non available dates. Put available dates clause in an `OR` condition

```
function unavailable(date) {

    ymd  = date.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2); 
    day = new Date(ymd).getDay();

    if (($.inArray(ymd, unavailableDates) < 0 && $.inArray(days[day], unavailableDays) < 0)
         || $.inArray(ymd, availableDates) >= 0) {
      return [true, "enabled", "Order now"];
    } else {
      return [false, "disabled", "Delivery not available on this date"];
    }
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83jrv1bt/)

Comment: Upvote both the answers if it helped and accept the one you implemented. It will help others looking for similar solution.